# How to store all the inputs in a list using a single command?

Tags: list, algorithm, input, data-structures

I was doing some ds and algo problems from faceprep and a question came:

***Amy Farrah Fowler asks her students to give 3 examples for positive odd numbers. When the student specifies a correct answer, his/her score is incremented by 1. When the student specifies a positive even number, his/her score is decremented by 0.5. When the student specifies a negative number, he/she will not be given any more chances to correct his or her mistake and his/her score will be decremented by 1. So a student's turn comes to an end when he/she has correctly specified 3 positive odd numbers or when the student has specified a negative number. Some students didn't know the difference between odd numbers and even numbers and they made many mistakes and so it was difficult for her to maintain the scores. She asks for your help. Can you please help her by writing a program to calculate the score?***

INPUT & OUTPUT FORMAT:

***Input consists of a list of integers.
The output consists of a single line. The score needs to be corrected to 1 decimal place.
[For this exercise, don't worry about duplicate odd numbers. Even if the students specify the same odd number thrice, it is accepted].***

input is given as:

1

2

3

4

5

Now How to take input and store it in a variable by single command?
till now I was doing but now number of inputs are different for each case study.
:

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
c=int(input())
```

I want to do this using a single command so that each input will store in a list.

Comment: will your input strictly separated by newline?

Comment: I don't know really. To store next input, I am doing m=int(input()) then for next input as n=int(input())

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet to store the input in the list "**List_w**".

```
List_w = []
try:
    while(1):
        List_w.append(int(input()))
except:
    print(List_w)
```

Answer (score 0):

if your `input` is separated by white space, you can use:

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(arr) # input 1 2 3 4 # output [1,2,3,4]
```

if your input is based on given range use:

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
    arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
    print(arr)
```

if the inputs separated by new line you can use `append` method or one liner:

```
arr = [int(input()) for _ in range(int(input()))]
print(arr) 

# input 
3 
4
5
6  # output [4, 5, 6]
```

know more about `input` here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-get-a-list-as-input-from-user/